# Who generates block details

Tags: mining, blocks

Who generates/computes the block header and other details such as ParentHash, TxHash, etc.? I refer to [image] above image for details but I am not sure who generates these details.

Answer (score 2):

The transaction hashes are self-evident from the transaction contents including the nonce. Normally, the `sender+nonce` combo is unique, so transaction hashes are unique. There is an exception (the "speed up" transaction trick) where the user rebroadcasts the same `sender+nonce` (usually with a higher `GasPrice`) and the second version *may* replace the unmined transaction if it gets mined first.

The miner assembles a block by selecting and ordering transactions received via gossip, a.k.a. the pending pool. Although there are incentives involved, the selection and order of the transactions are arbitrary with some constraints, for example:

1. Transactions from a given account must be in nonce order. A gap is not permitted. Alice cannot get nonce 11 confirmed while 10 is pending.
2. Transactions must be valid (but don't necessarily succeed). Failed transfers and contract interactions do get mined so that their failure is pseudo official. Since transactions usually depend on the pre-existing state, it's not possible to say they succeeded or failed until their place in the sequence of events is determined. By "invalid" we mean improperly signed or otherwise malformed.

The miner computes the hash of the block it created which takes as input the hash of the previous block where the new block is to be placed. It is not possible to generate a valid block 123 without knowing the hash of block 122.

A "valid" block observes all of the validation rules including the nonce that gave the miner the right to broadcast it. Nodes confirm the validity of received blocks and disregard those that don't add up.

Hope it helps.